# KeyTyped events - Why can I enter a character but when I delete I cannot enter anymore?

Tags: java, swing

I use this code to restrict the input only for numbers, but if the first key I press is a letter, the code let me enter that letter, only one time, then when I erase it I cannot input anymore letters, what is wrong with the code? I want to imput only numbers.

```
amount.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            if (!(Character.isDigit(c)
                    || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
                    || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))
                    || (amount.getText().length() >= 2)) {
                e.consume();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Consider instead either a `DocumentListener` (on the `Document` of the text field) or a `JSpinner` using a `SpinnerNumberModel` for this.

Answer (score 3):

Because of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

> "not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)".

Your condition is equivalent to:

```
if ((Character.isDigit(c) 
    && c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE
    && c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)) 
    || cantBannosTxt.getText().length() >= 2)
```

When you enter a two letters, the first part of the OR fails but the second one evaluates to `true`. Since `false || true` is `true`, it *will* consume what you entered.

I'll leave it for you to construct a new validation - Pay attention to the logical `&&` and `||` when combined with `!`.

Comment: I dont get it, why is relevant the AND  and OR. because if I delete that part still get the same results                                                                    if (!(Character.isDigit(c))) {
                    e.consume();
                }

Comment: The OP is checking if `!(isDigit || isBackSpace || isDelete) || len >= 2` ... Which shall be equivalent to `(isNotDigit && isNotBackSpace && isNotDelete) || len >= 2`. Maybe you missed the last edit.